# Can I use .net with Microsoft Dynamics systems?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have googled, but can´t find a good answer. I´m a .net developer and looking into starting with Microsoft Dynamics (CRM and AX). My question is if I can use .net on this platforms or do I have to learn x++?

Answer (score 1):

Yes .NET is the platform of choice for server-side customization of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327971.aspx. There's a lot of reading but you could be writing your first plugin in a few days.

I'm intentionally vague here because you should really take the time to read the materials out there to learn the right way.  It will help you out a lot more then me giving you a paragraph summary.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. "Yes" in x++ is a requirement or "Yes" as in I can use .NET?

Comment: You're welcome. No, x++ is not a requirement.  I don't know what x++ is.  "Yes" as in you can use .NET if you follow msdn from the link I provided and learn about CRM application development.  Specifically, plugin development would probably be the first thing you do.

Comment: I just googled and apparently x++ is the language for developing against Dynamics AX.  I haven't worked with AX only CRM.  If you are thinking CRM than my statement holds up.

Comment: @BrendonColburn X++ is a proprietary language for Dynamics AX ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867122.aspx)) and it make stuff easier. However, if the OP knows how to code .NET, he can get the job done that way. And picking up X++ will be fairly easy. Unless the employer requires expert level, in which case, it'll take a few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Dynamics CRM consists of a bunch of different customizational entries and some of them are .NET based (plugins, custom workflows, WCFs, external webs) while some are not (default workflows, JavaScript, XML customizations, FetchXML).

In my experience, at least based on the reality where I'm stationed, there's an abundance of people who can configure CRM **but** there's an embarrassing scarcity of skilled developer who can code .NET (and JS) to program the thing.

MS does what it can to make it possible to configure everything without coding but in the end, some things can't be resolved other than by good old hacking. Plugins is the golden goose, I'd say. If you learn how to write and install them, you're set. It's a bit of a threshold, that's true. But then again - if it'd be easy, everybody would be able to steal your job.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone who can tell how it is with MS ax or nav?

Comment: @Kran You'd need to elaborate the questions a bit. WHat are you asking about specifically?